# How to add corresponding columns to a PIVOT dataset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

I have a table:

```
PartID |TypeSet | Setting | ObservID |TransDate
---------------------------------------------
 1         A    456       12    10/20/2015
 1         A    377       12    10/20/2015
 1         A    425       12    10/20/2015
 1         A    665       12    10/20/2015
 1         A    543       12    10/20/2015
 1         A    554       12    10/20/2015
 1         B    34        41    10/21/2015
 1         B    27        41    10/21/2015
 1         B    27        41    10/21/2015
 1         B    29        41    10/21/2015
 1         C    1299      12    10/20/2015
 1         C    1227      12    10/20/2015
```

I would like to display it as the following. Single row grouped on PartID.

```
PartID | A Avg | B Avg | C Avg |  A ObservID | B ObservID | C ObservID
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  1      503      29     1263        12             41         12
```

I cannot get the ObservIDs to display w/o creating a multi-row return dataset. I have no problem with the A, B and C Average with this query:

```
  SELECT    
      PartID
      ,[A] as 'A Average'
      ,[B] as 'B Average'   
      ,[C] as 'C Average'
     -- ,(ObservID)
     --,CASE WHEN [A] = 'A Average' THEN max([ObservID]) END as 'A Ob'
     --,CASE WHEN [B] = 'B Average' THEN max([ObservID]) END as 'B Ob'
     -- ,CASE WHEN [C] = 'C Average' THEN max([ObservID]) END as 'C Ob'
FROM
(SELECT
    PartID  
    ,TypeSet
    ,Setting
    --,ObservID
    FROM  #Temp1
    ) as MeasData
PIVOT
(
    AVG(Setting) 
    FOR [TypeSet] in 
        ( [A], [B], [C])    
) as PivotTable
```

You can see in the above query where I've tried to get ObservID in it but when I uncomment those lines, errors occur.
Some notes: The ObservIDs will stay consistent for each TypeSet.

Here's the data:

```
create table #Temp1
(
  PartID INT
, TypeSet VARCHAR(10) 
, Setting INT
, ObservID INT
, TransDate Date
)

INSERT INTO #Temp1(PartID, TypeSet, Setting, ObservID, TransDate) VALUES
  (1, 'A', 456, 12, '10/20/2015'),
  (1, 'A', 377, 12, '10/20/2015'),
  (1, 'A', 425, 12, '10/20/2015'),
  (1, 'A', 665, 12, '10/20/2015'),
  (1, 'A', 543, 12, '10/20/2015'),
  (1, 'A', 554, 12, '10/20/2015'),
  (1, 'B', 34, 41, '10/21/2015'),
  (1, 'B', 27, 41, '10/21/2015'),
  (1, 'B', 27, 41, '10/21/2015'),
  (1, 'B', 29, 41, '10/21/2015'),
  (1, 'C', 1299, 12, '10/20/2015'),
  (1, 'C', 1227, 12, '10/20/2015')
```

Is my desired output possible with the PIVOT operation? Or should I go the route of multiple JOINs on the table for each Typeset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT PartID,
     AVG(CASE WHEN TypeSet = 'A' THEN Setting END) AS 'A Avg',
     AVG(CASE WHEN TypeSet = 'B' THEN Setting END) AS 'B Avg',
     AVG(CASE WHEN TypeSet = 'C' THEN Setting END) AS 'C Avg',
     MAX(CASE WHEN TypeSet = 'A' THEN ObservID END) AS 'A ObservID',
     MAX(CASE WHEN TypeSet = 'B' THEN ObservID END) AS 'B ObservID',
     MAX(CASE WHEN TypeSet = 'C' THEN ObservID END) AS 'C ObservID'
FROM #Temp1
GROUP BY PartID
```

Comment: This is great. Gets me what I need. My only concern is the performance but at the same time, I haven't reviewed the explain plans...But thank you for this.

Comment: @Charlie This should be as fast as any query using `PIVOT`. `PIVOT` is actually syntactic sugar for conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

```
  WITH avgPivot AS
(
  SELECT 
      PartID,[a] as A_Avg,[b] as B_Avg,[c] as C_Avg
  FROM
  (
    SELECT PartID, TypeSet, Setting, ObservID
    FROM #Temp1
  ) As S
  PIVOT
  (
     AVG(Setting)
     FOR TypeSet in([a],[b],[c])
  )
  AS pvt
),
maxPivot AS
(
  SELECT 
       [a] as A_ObservID, [B]B_ObservID, [c] as c_ObservID
  FROM
  (
    SELECT PartID, TypeSet, Setting, ObservID
    FROM #Temp1
  ) As S
  PIVOT
  (
     max(ObservID)
     FOR TypeSet in([a],[b],[c])
  )
  AS pvt
)

SELECT distinct *
FROM avgPivot M
 cross JOIN maxPivot A
```

Comment: This gives me NULLs and creates a multi-row dataset.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear but yes, single row based on PartID